# Is it possible if I put .fit() at the end of GridSearchCV() in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Example code:

```
parameter_svc = {'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1]}
model_svc =  GridSearchCV(SVC(random_state=rng), parameter_svc)
model_svc.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

If possible if I reduce the number of lines by doing

```
parameter_svc = {'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1]}
model_svc =  GridSearchCV(SVC(random_state=rng), parameter_svc).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Did you try it and did not work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. It's called method chaining and it's common.  :)

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie.

Comment: No worries, we've all been there. :)  Would you mind marking mine as the accepted answer? Thanks